# Neural Network Bias updating during BackProp

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, bias

Can it make sense to say that when I update the weights in a positive way in a neural network also the bias is updated in a positive way and that therefore the trend of weight and bias for the activation of a certain neuron are proportional?

In other words, let's imagine that I want to activate a neuron that defines a certain function for a feature that recognizes the importance of some values of an input x , such as x0 , x1 , x2 for a given example. Let's suppose that I give an example with very high values for x0 , x1 , x2 ; I can say that this neuron, after training, will be activated.

Now let's imagine that I provide another input with a very high value of x0 but low value for x1 and x2. Will this neuron still be activated or will I not reach the activation value because of the bias? Or will another neuron be activated that recognizes the importance of x0? If this neuron is activated, should I deduce that its bias for activation is lower than that of the previous neuron ?

Comment: I think that this question is entirely too abstract to be answerable. You talk about "activation" as if neurons are "on" or "off", but many neuron activations are continuous-valued. Instead of framing a very abstract and hypothetical question, could you re-write your question to focus on what problem you are trying to solve, and how updates to weights and biases relates to that problem? Are you trying to explain in plain English how NNs work, or are you trying to gain intuition about what happens during network training? Or something else?

Comment: yes, I'm just trying to understand how the term bias is updated when I use the gradient descent and the back prop to optimize the parameters, if my weights are updated by a positive term, will be positive also the bias?

Comment: Please edit your question to make that more clear. Right now, it is accumulating closure votes because it is unclear.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me such an unclear question, i'm asking how the bias is updated during the back prop

Comment: I think that your comments are much more clear than your question! Even if you know exactly what your question means, other people might have a hard time deciphering it -- and other people are the ones who get to vote on closing/opening questions.